# Pywin32 Working directly with Columns and Rows like it would be done in VBA

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I am starting to migrate some of my VBA code into Python, because it gives me more resources. However I am having troubles to work in similar way.

I wanted to clear some Columns, however I cannot work directly with the attribute Columns of the worksheet. And I have to do turnarounds like this (full code):

```
import win32com.client as win32

xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = True

wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(r'Test.xlsx')
sh = wb.ActiveSheet

xl.ScreenUpdating = True
last_col = sh.UsedRange.Columns.Count
last_row = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
my_range = sh.Range(sh.Cells(1, 1), sh.Cells(last_row, 4))
my_range.Select()
xl.Selection.ClearContents()
```

So, what I would like to do, is like in VBA:

```
Columns("A:D").Clear
```

Is there any way to work with rows and columns with Python, and not only with ranges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply run: `sh.Columns("A:D").Clear`. It should be noted that you are not translating VBA code to Python. Both languages are doing the same thing in making a COM interface to the Excel Object library. Because the Office applications ships with VBA, it is often believed that VBA *is* the language for these softwares and the language is natively built-in but VBA is actually a component. Under Tools/References in IDE, you will see VBA is first checked item.

So, with the Windows [Component Object Model (COM)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680573(v=vs.85).aspx), any general purpose language including Python, PHP, R, Java, C#, etc. can connect to the Excel Object Library and make calls to workbook objects and methods. You just have to adhere to the languages' syntax. As example:

**Python** *(win32com module)*

```py
sh.Columns("A:D").Clear()
```

**PHP** *([COM](http://php.net/manual/en/class.com.php) class)*

```php
sh->Columns("A:D")->Clear()
```

**R** *([RDCOMClient](http://www.omegahat.net/RDCOMClient/Docs/introduction.html) module)*

```r
sh$Columns("A:D")$Clear()
```

---

Also, consider running your code in `try...except...finally` blocks to catch exceptions and properly uninitialize COM objects regardless if your code errors out or not. Otherwise, the Excel.exe process will continue running in background.

```
import win32com.client as win32

try:
    xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    xl.Visible = True

    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\Path\To\Test.xlsx')
    sh = wb.ActiveSheet

    xl.ScreenUpdating = True
    sh.Columns("A:D").Clear()

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    sh = None
    wb = None
    xl = None
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped. I am going to take into account your advise of the block try...except.